# How does a Smart Contract know the gas/fees needed to execute a transaction?

Tags: solidity, gas, consensus, out-of-gas

I installed recently Solidity for Visual Studio and they have this Smart Contract sample there:

> ```
> contract Payout {
> address Victor;
> address Jim;
> address Kieren;
>
> mapping (address => uint) ownershipDistribution; 
>
> function Setup() {
>   Victor = 0xaabb;
>   Jim    = 0xccdd;
>   Kieren = 0xeeff;
>
>   ownershipDistribution[Victor] = 35;
>   ownershipDistribution[Jim]  = 35;
>   ownershipDistribution[Kieren] = 30;
> }
>
> function Dividend() {
>   uint bal= this.balance;
>   Victor.send(bal * ownershipDistribution[Victor] / 100); 
>   Jim.send(bal * ownershipDistribution[Jim] / 100);
>   Kieren.send(bal * ownershipDistribution[Kieren] / 100);
> }
> }
> ```

Basically it is supposed to send the ethers it receives to 3 addresses.

But I believe the code as it is won't work, as the last transaction won't have enough gas, right? Only the first 2 would execute.

Imagine there's 10 ETH in the contract, 3.5 Eth + fees / gas will be sent to address A, 3.5 Eth + fees / gas will be sent to address B, now we dont have the remaining needed 3 Eth for the third address...

So how can the Smart Contract know in the advance the gas/fees needed for the transactions?

Comment: Why won't the last transaction have enough gas? This looks like it would work fine.

Comment: Image there 10 ETH in the contract, 3.5 Eth + fees / gas will be sent to address A, 3.5 Eth + fees / gas will be sent to address B, now we dont have the remaining needed 3 Eth for the third address... Right?

Comment: Fees come from the account of the sender, not the Payout contract.  Sender has their ETH balance which is different from Payout contract's ETH balance.

Comment: So you are saying, when the dividend method is called the ethereum protocol will automatically detect that there are 3 transactions inside of it and the transaction costs for fees and gas for those 3 transactions will be presented for the sender to pay when he does the transaction calling that method?

Comment: Calls to other contracts and to send aren't separate transactions: they occur as part of the same transaction the contract is running in, and use the same gas counter, with gas supplied by the caller of the original contract.

Comment: So the answer to the question of my previous comment is yes?

Answer (score 4):

Basically, miners and contracts do not know in advance the gas/fees needed for a transaction: they have to run the code in the transaction to find out.  This is why the `gas` specified in a transaction, is the maximum amount that the transaction is willing to consume.

---

To answer the intended question, fees are paid from the balance of the sender account (the account that calls `Dividend`), which is different from the balance of the `Payout` contract which is divided between Victor et al.

Comment: But how can this code work then if we dont know the fees and gas in advance? The third transaction will never execute

Comment: I answered the general question which is a good one.  The example asked in the question was confusing, but I understand what you're asking now and commented to the question that "Fees come from the account of the sender, not the Payout contract."

Comment: I updated the answer; will cleanup some comments if they're no longer needed.

Comment: So in other words, what I asked in my last comment on the question is what will happen?

Answer (score 4):

Think about gas like it's gas in your car. You don't need to know in advance exactly how much gas you're going to use; you just buy more than you think you'll need, and if you run out then the car just stops.

In this case, the sender sends a certain amount of gas with the transaction. As the code is executed, the miner keeps track of how much gas had been used so far. If the execution runs out of gas, the execution just stops, and the whole transaction is reverted as it never happened. The miner gets to keep the gas, though.